# Eigen function that does array operations on Matrix<> or Block<>

Tags: c++, eigen

I'd like to make a function that can take both a Matrix<> or a Block<> object.

Example:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/Dense>

//A simplified example of the function I'm making
double example_function(const Eigen::MatrixXd & input){
    double d1 = input.array().pow(2).sum();
    double d2 = input.rowwise().norm().sum();
    return d1 + d2;
}


int main(){
    Eigen::MatrixXd m1(3,2);
    m1.setRandom();

    // This works
    example_function(m1);

    // I'd like to make this work
    example_function(m1.block(1,0,2,2));

    return 0;
}
```

The following does **not** work, because DenseBase does not have the 'array' method:

```cpp
template<typename Derived>
double example_function(const Eigen::DenseBase<Derived> & input){
    double d1 = input.array().pow(2).sum();  // array() method invalid 
    double d2 = input.rowwise().norm().sum();
    return d1 + d2;
}
```

How would I go about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, your original code (with `const MatrixXd&`) does work, but it can generate an unnecessary copy. To accept both `Matrix<...>` and `Block<Matrix<...> >` objects via a templated function, use `MatrixBase` instead of `DenseBase`:

```
template<class Derived>
double example_function(const Eigen::MatrixBase<Derived> & input){
    double d1 = input.array().abs2().sum(); // abs2() is simpler/more efficient than pow(2)
    double d2 = input.rowwise().norm().sum();
    return d1 + d2;
}
```

However, in your example code `m1.block(1,0)` is invalid, as you need to specify the size as well as the start-index, e.g., these work:

```
m1.block<1,2>(1,0);
m1.block(1,0, 1,2);
```

and `m1.Random()` should be `m1.setRandom()`.

Comment: Thanks, I've corrected those things. I should actually run the sample code next time...

Answer (score 2):

If both kinds of object support the operations you wish to perform, then:

```
template <typename T>
double example_function(const T& input){
    double d1 = input.array().pow(2).sum();
    double d2 = input.rowwise().norm().sum();
    return d1 + d2;
}
```

Comment: If not then you're going to have to expand on what you wish to do!